# $http.post() angularjs response function not executing in right order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From my angular controller I'm making a function call to do $http.post() request.

```
$scope.formSuccess = false;

$scope.submit = function(serviceName) {
   submitRequest(serviceName);
   if($scope.formSuccess) {
      // do something 
    }
};

var submitRequest = function(serviceName) {
   $http.post(serviceName, data, { headers: { 'Content-type':   'application/json' }  
  }).then(successFunction, errorFunction);
};

var successFunction = function(response) {
  $scope.formSuccess =true;
};
```

the code below the submitRequest() is executing first than the successFunction() so  the code inside if block is never executing. how can i do that. I don't want to move if block to successFunction.

Comment: This isn't going to work. Your service gets called, then the if formSuccess runs and will always return false because your http request will never be done before that if statement. Please read the docs regarding http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http Also another link with better examples https://thinkster.io/http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line `if($scope.formSuccess) {` is executed before `http` request is done, hence the statement inside the `if` is never executed.

The cleanest solution would be to introduce functions to be execute on `$http.post` success and failure

```js
$scope.formSuccess = false;

$scope.submit = function(serviceName) {
   submitRequest(serviceName)
    .then(onPostSuccess)
    .catch(onPostFail);
};

var submitRequest = function(serviceName) {
   return $http.post(serviceName, data, { headers: { 'Content-type':   'application/json' }  
   });
};

var onPostSuccess = function(response) {
  $scope.formSuccess = true;
  //do your stuff here
  
};

var onPostFail = function(response){
  $scope.formSuccess = false;
  //show form failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in *submit* function if($scope.formSuccess) does not waiting for http response. So its always false, You need put it inside promise function

```
var successFunction = function(response) {
  $scope.formSuccess =true;
  // do what you want in here

};
```